# WPF app debug argument runs OK but is ignored on CMD

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF app that needs to get a parameter that allows to select the screen it has to be displayed.
It works like a charm when I use the "Command line arguments" feature on "Project right click -> Properties -> Debug".The problem comes when I publish the app and I try to pass an argument using CMD, because it's completely ignored.
Here's the code:
App.xaml.cs class

```
  private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            log.Debug("Paramerters: " + e.Args.Length);
            foreach (var parameter in e.Args )
            {
                log.Debug("Arg " + parameter);
            }
            var screen = 0;
            if (e.Args.Length > 0)
            {
                if(Int32.TryParse(e.Args[0], out screen))
                {
                    log.Debug("Parameter: " + screen);
                } else
                {
                    log.Debug("Invalid parameter : " + e.Args[0]);
            }
        }

        log.Debug("Screen: " + screen);
        App.Current.Properties["Screen"] = screen;
        log.Debug("Screens count: " + System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.Length);

        if (screen >= System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.Length)
        {
            log.Debug("Error screens count: " + System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.Length);
            App.Current.Shutdown();
        }
        else
        {
            var screen1 = App.Current.Properties["Screen"];
            MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
            var screenBounds = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[screen].Bounds;
            mainWindow.Left = screenBounds.Left;
            mainWindow.Top = screenBounds.Top;
            mainWindow.Show();
            mainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        }
    }
```

Am I missing something? I'm using the next line to start the app(it does start, but the argument is always the default one):
AppName 1
Also, i have more than 1 screen for sure.

Edit with the logs output:

2018-10-31 12:42:20,366 [  1] DEBUG                            App - Paramerters: 0

2018-10-31 12:42:20,396 [  1] DEBUG                            App - Screen: 0

2018-10-31 12:42:20,401 [  1] DEBUG                            App - Screens count: 2

Comment: It's not read as 0. 0 is the *default* value. `if (e.Args.Length == 1)` means that if there are *more* than 1 argument, all of them get ignored. Change the condition to `>0` at least and add a logging statement that logs the entire event

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'va changed the code, and as you can see the number of Parameters(Args) I've got is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it seems than using a reference to the app does not work.
I've put the full route to the App and it does work. It should be something similar to:
C:\Users\SMACS\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\MMA17POZ.R0G\PHXLDOK5.2Y8\pane..tion_d85c1227db19dafd_0001.0000_ae3906090ab02453